# ImageAnalysis.Analyzer does nothing when it is put on cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore, android-camerax, google-mlkit

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.memex.eu

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Size
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult
import com.google.ar.core.Plane
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.ObjectDetection
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.ObjectDetector
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.defaults.ObjectDetectorOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.function.Consumer
import java.util.function.Function

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private val TAG: String = MainActivity::class.java.getSimpleName()
    private var arFragment: ArFragment? = null
    private var andyRenderable: ModelRenderable? = null
    private lateinit var options: ObjectDetectorOptions
    private lateinit var objectDetector: ObjectDetector
    private lateinit var analyzer: MyImageAnalyzer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        if (!checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this)) {
            return
        }

        arFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.sceneform_fragment) as ArFragment?

        // When you build a Renderable, Sceneform loads its resources in the background while returning
        // a CompletableFuture. Call thenAccept(), handle(), or check isDone() before calling get().
        ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, R.raw.andy)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(Consumer { renderable: ModelRenderable? ->
                andyRenderable = renderable
            })
            .exceptionally(
                Function<Throwable, Void?> { throwable: Throwable? ->
                    val toast =
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                    toast.show()
                    null
                })
        arFragment!!.setOnTapArPlaneListener { hitResult: HitResult, plane: Plane?, motionEvent: MotionEvent? ->
            if (andyRenderable == null) {
                return@setOnTapArPlaneListener
            }

            // Create the Anchor.
            val anchor = hitResult.createAnchor()
            val anchorNode =
                AnchorNode(anchor)
            anchorNode.setParent(arFragment!!.arSceneView.scene)

            // Create the transformable andy and add it to the anchor.
            val andy =
                TransformableNode(arFragment!!.transformationSystem)
            andy.setParent(anchorNode)
            andy.renderable = andyRenderable
            andy.select()
        }

        // Live detection and tracking
        options = ObjectDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setDetectorMode(ObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
                .enableClassification()  // Optional
                .build()

        objectDetector = ObjectDetection.getClient(options)

        @androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
        analyzer = MyImageAnalyzer()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
        IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())
                    }

            val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, analyzer)
                    }

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer)

            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)

        private const val MIN_OPENGL_VERSION = 3.0

        /**
         * Returns false and displays an error message if Sceneform can not run, true if Sceneform can run
         * on this device.
         *
         *
         * Sceneform requires Android N on the device as well as OpenGL 3.0 capabilities.
         *
         *
         * Finishes the activity if Sceneform can not run
         */
        fun checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(activity: Activity): Boolean {
            val openGlVersionString =
                (activity.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
                    .deviceConfigurationInfo
                    .glEsVersion
            if (openGlVersionString.toDouble() < MIN_OPENGL_VERSION) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 later")
                Toast.makeText(
                    activity,
                    "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or later",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                )
                    .show()
                activity.finish()
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

MyImageAnalyzer.kt

```
package com.memex.eu

import android.util.Log
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.DetectedObject
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.ObjectDetection
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.defaults.ObjectDetectorOptions
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.defaults.PredefinedCategory

@androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
class MyImageAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer{
    // Live detection and tracking
    val options = ObjectDetectorOptions.Builder()
        .setDetectorMode(ObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
        .enableClassification()  // Optional
        .build()
    val objectDetector = ObjectDetection.getClient(options)
    private val TAG: String = MyImageAnalyzer::class.java.getSimpleName()

    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
        Log.e(TAG, "DETECTIONS")
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

            objectDetector.process(image)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    imageProxy.close()
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        displayDets(it.result as List<DetectedObject>)
                    } else {
                        it.exception?.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
        }
        imageProxy.close()
    }

    private fun displayDets(results: List<DetectedObject>) {
        for (detectedObject in results) {
            val boundingBox = detectedObject.boundingBox
            val trackingId = detectedObject.trackingId
            for (label in detectedObject.labels) {
                val text = label.text
                if (PredefinedCategory.FOOD == text) {
                    Log.e(TAG, text)
                }
                val index = label.index
                if (PredefinedCategory.FOOD_INDEX == index) {
                    Log.e(TAG, text)
                }
                val confidence = label.confidence
                Log.e(TAG, confidence.toString())
                Log.e(TAG, trackingId.toString())
                Log.e(TAG, boundingBox.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in my console, I see none of the Log statements from ImageAnalysis.Analyzer. What's going on? Why is ImageAnalysis.Analyzer not being called? I am printing out the log statements first before I eventually draw the bounding boxes. However, the analyze function of ImageAnalysis.Analyzer is not being called at all. How do I tell camerax to call that function?

Comment: Could you share logs from when you run the app. Also, does the preview show up?

Comment: Does the preview use case work correctly?